# Establish ranges in array of Doubles

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking to establish the various ranges that may exist in an array of Double values. This is best explained with an example. Say I have the following set of numbers:

```
[1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 4.0]
```

I would like to be able to determine, with a given granularity (in this case 0.1), that the ranges in this set are:

```
1.5-1.8, 2.9-3.1, 4.0
```

Any ideas?

Example data set for granularity of 0.01:

```
[407.46, 407.47, 407.48, 407.49, 407.5, 407.51, 407.52, 407.53, 407.54, 407.55, 407.56, 407.57, 407.58, 407.59, 407.6, 407.61, 407.62, 407.63, 407.64, 407.65, 407.66, 407.67, 407.68, 407.69, 407.7, 407.71, 407.72, 407.73, 407.74, 407.75, 407.76, 407.77, 407.78, 407.79, 407.8, 407.81, 407.82, 407.83, 407.84, 407.85, 407.86, 407.87, 407.88, 407.89, 407.9, 407.91, 440.27, 440.28, 440.29, 440.3, 440.31, 440.32, 440.33, 440.34, 440.35, 440.36, 440.37, 440.38, 440.39, 440.4, 440.41, 440.42, 440.43, 440.44, 440.45, 440.46, 440.47, 440.48, 440.49, 440.5, 440.51, 440.52, 440.53, 440.54, 440.55, 440.56, 440.57, 440.58, 440.59, 440.6, 440.61, 440.62, 440.63, 440.64, 440.65, 440.66, 440.67, 440.68, 440.69, 440.7, 440.71, 440.72, 440.73, 440.74]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A longer and simpler implementation:

```
func getRanges(from values: [Double], with granularity: Double) -> [ClosedRange<Double>] {
    if values.count == 1 {
        return [values[0]...values[0]]
    }

    var ranges = [ClosedRange<Double>]()
    var lowerBound: Double = 0
    var upperBound: Double = 0

    for (i, value) in values.enumerated() {
        if i == 0 {
            lowerBound = value
            upperBound = value
            continue
        }
        
        let multiplier: Double = (1 / granularity).rounded()
        let multipliedGranularity = granularity * multiplier
        if (value * multiplier - (upperBound * multiplier + multipliedGranularity)).isLess(than: multipliedGranularity) {
            upperBound = value
        } else {
            ranges.append(lowerBound...upperBound)
            lowerBound = value
            upperBound = value
        }
        
        if i == values.count - 1 {
            ranges.append(lowerBound...upperBound)
        }
    }
    
    return ranges
}
```

Using your sample the result is:

```
ClosedRange(407.46...407.91)
ClosedRange(440.27...440.74)
```

This code works even with smaller granularities. For example, with granularity `0.0000000001` and the following values:

```
[407.9999999991, 407.9999999992, 407.9999999994, 407.9999999995]
```

result:

```
ClosedRange(407.9999999991...407.9999999992)
ClosedRange(407.9999999994...407.9999999995)
```

Comment: @user13138159 you're correct, the algorithm had a problem comparing double values check it out now.

Comment: If there is only one Double in the array, the array is returned empty, it should return that Double. Should I just do I check on the count of the [Double] and only proceed to try to find a range if > 1?

Comment: @user13138159 yes you can check on the count.